# print prime no from 1 to n while n is entered through the keyboard

Tags: c

i know my code is little bit weird but i just started coding
can some one please help me figure out why my code is not working

```
    int n,i,j;
    printf("enter the value\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
       for(j=2;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if( (i%j==0) && (i!=j)  )
            {
                 break;
            }
            else if(i!=j)
            {
                 continue;
            }
        }
        if(i==j)
        {
              printf("prime no are %d\n",i);
               continue;
        }
   }
```

Comment: You don't need any of the `continue;`. Also why this `(i!=j)`  in `if` block ?

Comment: You only break if i!=j and the loop only exits on its own when j>i, so the test to print  never succeeds.

Comment: Actually he breaks when (i%j==0) && (i!=j), so until the last iteration there are no problems, and at the last this code is then executed :
if(i==j)
        {
              printf("prime no are %d\n",i);
               continue;
        }

Comment: When asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.  This includes code that cleanly compiles, example of an input, the expected output, and the actual output.  To start, the posted code does not compile,  It is missing the needed `#include` statements.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your actual code is including?

Comment: What's your code doing?  think that when you say _my code is not working_ you have to explain how is it not working?  We don't see your screen, and you don't post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program does not record When a number is prime. Try :

```
    int n,i,j,prime_count;
    bool is_prime;

    printf("enter the value\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    prime_count = 0;

    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
       is_prime = true;

       for(j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
            if( (i%j) == 0 )
              {
                 is_prime = false;
                 break;
              }

            // As said by Achal you may not need this condition, 
            // Your loop will continue by itself
            // else if(i!=j)
            //  {
            //     continue;
            //  }
        }
        if(is_prime)
           {
              prime_count++;
            }
   }

   // Then you can do what you want with the number of primes found
   // e.g. print it :
   printf("Number of primes: %d\n", prime_count);
```

Comment: Wouldn't prime_count be incremented only in cases where the number it not prime?

Comment: well thanku abel , i understood the above code and finally my code worked but can you please elaborate your above comment i.e      Actually he breaks when (i%j==0) && (i!=j), so until the last iteration there are no problems, and at the last this code is then executed : if(i==j) { printf("prime no are %d\n",i); continue; }

Comment: I commented this because I guessed your intend with the conditions (i!=j) and (i!=j) was to dissociate the loop running and the end of loop. And even if this was not the problem in your implementation, this could look awkward for at least 3 reasons :

Comment: - in the nested for-loop you don't need to increment j until its value is the same as i, so you could write 'j < i' instead of 'j <= i' (and even j < i/2 is sufficient to find prime factor),
- the if(i==j) attempts to execute the code inside the condition at the end of the loop, but at each iteration the program will make the comparison and that is not efficient. In your case you can just move the code after the loop.

Comment: - Finally you don't need the (i!=j) condition, i guess you put it to avoid breaking at the last iteration when i==j, thus allowing your 'continue' instruction and printf  to be executed but since the last should be placed outside you do not need this condition.

Despite what I said above, the only thing that prevent your program from working was the fact that you did not make the count when detecting a prime. The rest was just a bit weird as you said :)

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is off by 1.  It should be:

```
for(j=2;j<i;j++)
```

Currently j will be i+1 if the number is prime so you final check fails